# Compile Error : ( Warning: Control Reaches End of Non-Void Function [-Wreturn-type] )

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to compile my code using this:`g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o test10 program10.cpp` This occurs:

```
program10.cpp: In function 'int getInt(std::string)':
program10.cpp:76:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Here is the code:

```
int getInt(string str) {
    string bin[] = {"11000", "00011", "00101", "00110", "01001",
                    "01010", "01100", "10001", "10010", "10100"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (str.compare(bin[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't return a value in all cases. Think of how you would test all paths through that function and you should be able to find an input that doesn't return a value.

Comment: If the string doesn't match any of the patterns, then what happens?

Comment: I suggest you searching the internet before asking questions here.

Comment: Google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

If none of the strings in the array match the function's parameter string, your function will never return anything even though it is supposed to return an int. I would suggest returning something like -1 as the last statement of the function to indicate when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your warning was explained concisely by the compiler. The code is only reaching your `return` statement when one of the strings in the `bin` array is found. This is one of the many reasons you should prefer a single exit point (makes for better readability, won't cause this warning, and easier to debug).  You should also prefer passing non-POD types as reference for function arguments.

```
int getInt(string & str)
{
    int ret(-1); // bias to error
    string bin[] = {"11000", "00011", "00101", "00110", "01001",
        "01010", "01100", "10001", "10010", "10100"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (str.compare(bin[i]) == 0) {
            ret = i; // success!
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```